# ds1307 incorrect timing

Tags: arduino

i built a clock circuit using ds1307 and atmega328 and it works very fine
but i noticed that the time of my clock is increment by 6 seconds in a day (approx) by comparing to my computer clock 
what is the problem could be?? i used the DS because it gives a real time clock 
i used the crystal that came with the ds1307 when i bought it?
could it be the ds has a kind of problem ?
or should i but a capacitors on the crystal?

thanks any way

Comment: What does the data sheet say about the crystal circuit?

Comment: Your computer clock might be slow.

Comment: +1 on gbarry's comment, my PC clock is really bad (have seen drift over 20 seconds in a day) so maybe compare against http://nist.time.gov/ to make sure it's not your PC.

Comment: @LeonHeller the data sheet did not say any thing more about the crystal circuit but they mention to ground the crystal but  I don't think the incorrect due to the grounding thing ,do it?? ***gbarry I used the link that ***peterj put it here and thnks to him of course, by the comparing to my pc clock there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

The best comparison clock to use to validate your DS1307 circuit is a mains-powered one - the utility takes great pains to ensure that the line frequency is very stable. A GPS clock would be a good choice, as would a local radio station that broadcasts time.

As for your DS1307, if you look up [application note 58](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN504.pdf) it makes mention of specific load capacitors and crystals. You should make sure that you're using the correct load capacitors with the crystal you have. If you're not sure, you can try using something in the range of values specified in the table and re-evaluate your error.

[image: excerpt from app note 58]

Comment: The DS1307 has its load capacitors internally and doesn't require any externally